# How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose but return all of the doc?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Using mongoose and it's distinct function... how can i combine a find with regex and distict, and return the full document?

Using the distinct function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#options just returns the unique fields.

This is what i instead cobbled together with lodash..

```
findByTitle: ( title ) => {
    return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

        solutionModel.find( {"Title": { $regex: new RegExp( title ,'i') }}, (err, docs) => {
            if( err ) return reject( err );

            return resolve( _.uniqBy(docs, (e) => {
                return e.SolutionID;
            }) );
        });

    } );
},
```

Trailing with aggregate:

```
solutionModel.aggregate(
    [
        { "$match": {
            "Title": { $regex: new RegExp( 't' ,'i') }
        }},
        // Grouping pipeline
        { "$group": {
            "SolutionID": '$SolutionID'
        }},
        // Sorting pipeline
        { "$sort": { "Title": -1 } },
        // Optionally limit results
        // { "$limit": 5 }
    ],
    function(err,docs) {

        console.log( err );
        console.log( docs );
    }
);
```

Results in error:

> MongoError: The field 'SolutionID' must be an accumulator object

Comment: use aggregation: apply the `$regex` in a **`$match`** stage, and then group by `SolutionID` in a **`$group`** stage

Comment: @felix when i try with aggregates i get errors.. :/  I added my attempt the answer...

Comment: your not far, just replace `SolutionID` in **`$group`** by `_id` so your group stage looks like : `{$group: {_id: "$SolutionID"}}` . If you want to keep the other fields, have a look at the `$first` operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong syntax for $group. Please read https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/.

E.g. grouping by SolutionID, storing the first matching document in 'doc':

```
{ "$group": {
    _id: "$SolutionID",
    doc: {$first: "$$ROOT"}
}
```