# Return whole document in MongoDB with distinct fields and 1 select query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm having trouble writing a query that returns the whole document while still having 1 distinct field.
I already tried to mess with Aggregates but to no avail. I already found this document after googling some time:

[How to efficiently perform "distinct" with multiple keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973725/how-to-efficiently-perform-distinct-with-multiple-keys)

It describes most of the solution i need, but i need to filter on another field as well.

This is the function I use right now to query a sorted list of the documents in the TempCollection.

```
function getLatestUserData(UserID, callback) {
  console.log("in func      " + UserID);
  Temp.find({ UId: UserID }).sort({ "created_at" : -1 }).exec( function (err, data) {
    console.log(data + "     " + err);
    callback(data);
  });
};
```

however, I cannot figure out how I can filter, sort and distinct all at the same time.

This is an attempt at using Aggregates, however, read articles for quite some time and I just can't figure out the syntax for the purpose I need:

```
function getLatestUserData(UserID, callback) {
  Temp.aggregate([

    {"$group": { "_id": { value: "$value", SerialNumber: "$SerialNumber" } }},
    {$filter : {input: "$UId", as: "UId", cond: {$U: [ "$UId", UserID ]} }}
  ]).exec( function (err, data) {
    callback(data);
  });
};
```

Here is a part of the TempCollection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-05-23T13:01:45.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-23T13:01:45.000Z"),
    "UId" : "590b10221da091b2618a4913",
    "value" : 36,
    "SerialNumber" : "TEST2",
    "_id" : ObjectId("592432b9372464833d038b80"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-05-23T14:23:39.000Z"),
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-05-23T14:23:39.000Z"),
    "UId" : "58f8954c3602b80552b6f1fb",
    "value" : 39,
    "SerialNumber" : "IIOJOIMJ",
    "_id" : ObjectId("592445eb372464833d038bf4"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I query for distinct values in Mongoose but return all of the doc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43895084/how-do-i-query-for-distinct-values-in-mongoose-but-return-all-of-the-doc)

Comment: You will need to add the `$match` and `$sort` stage followed by `$group` with `$$ROOT` from the linked dups.

Comment: @Veeram Then give them an answer. The question shows `$filter` so pointing out the difference with [Pipeline Aggregation Stages](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to general operators in an answer would be nice

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add `$match` on `UID` instead of `$filter` ( only used with array fields 
) followed by desc `$sort` on `created_at` and `$group` on distinct keys while using `$$ROOT` variable inside of `$first` accumulation operator to pick the latest whole document.

Something like

```
 Temp.aggregate([
    {"$match":{ "UId": UserID }},
    {"$sort":{ "created_at" : -1 }},
    {"$group": { "_id": { value: "$value", SerialNumber: "$SerialNumber" }, "data":{"$first":"$$ROOT"}}}
  ])
```

The `data` field will have the latest doc.

Comment: Looks great! However, when i execute this `data = Temp.aggregate([
    {"$match":{ "UId": UserID }},
    {"$sort":{ "created_at" : -1 }},
    {"$group": { "_id": { value: "$value", SerialNumber: "$SerialNumber" }, "data":{"$push":"$$ROOT"}}}
  ]).exec(function(err,data) {
    console.log(data);
    callback(data);
  });` it returns `undefined`

Comment: I did update the answer after you've used the code. Use `$first` instead of `$push` and aside from that I do get the data back.